# How to use g.formatNumber in grails Service class

Tags: grails, gsp, number-formatting, grails-services

I want to use g.formatNumber in service, I have tried a below method, Which i got online. This is not working, its giving me the error `"Cannot invoke method formatNumber() on null object"`, The code is below

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

    class MyService implements InitializingBean {
        boolean transactional = false
        def gspTagLibraryLookup  // being automatically injected by spring
        def g

        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            g = gspTagLibraryLookup.lookupNamespaceDispatcher("g")
            assert g
        }

      def getFormattedNumber(){
       def number = g.formatNumber(number: 5000,234 , type: "number" , maxFractionDigits: 2)
       return number
     }
}
```

How to do this.

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in formatNumber(). Could you check if _g_ is null inside getFormattedNumber()?

Comment: I think @HernánErasmo is right.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to use g.formatNumber in service

Rather than jumping through the hoops you need to use a taglib within a service, it would be simpler to just use `java.text.NumberFormat` directly

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()
format.maximumFractionDigits = 2
def number = format.format(5000.234)
```

If the service method is being called from a web request handling thread then you may wish to use the [LocaleContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html) to get the correct locale for the current web request, rather than just using the server's default.

Comment: Yes, This is always a solution But for using especially g tag in service was my question

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib');
```

You will of course need grailsApplication injected by defining it ala

```
def grailsApplication
```

Comment: From grails 2.1


`import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def g = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')`

Comment: in grails 4.0.13 `def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib');` worked for me